# How to re-write request URI along with path variable in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 4 right now and I have a controller defined a such:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/definitions", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public List<ResponseDTO> update(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
                                HttpServletRequest iRequest) throws Exception 
{ ... }
```

I am expecting to receive an encrypted 'id' String coming as part of a path variable in the request itself. But what I need to do is re-write this request URI and decrypt it to another value (an integer, for example) and form another HTTP request with the original URI only with the transformed/decrypted value.

How can I get a hold of the entire URI and substitute the {id} with an integer?

For example, if the original request coming in looks like:

```
http://mycompany.com/my-service/kjAISOhalkjZjakmbbb/definitions
```

I want to transform everything after the context path:

```
/kjAISOhalkjZjakmbbb/definitions
```

to:

```
/123456/definitions
```

So finally, I can form a request to another service that might look like this:

```
http://mycompany.com/my-service-2/123456/definitions
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you plan on decrypting it...decrypting it from what? how is it encrypted or  is that not part of your question?

Comment: Also, you claim you want to send them to another URI. Yet, you are returning a list of objects from you controller method. You can't do both.

Answer (score 0):

Decrypt the value (however you do that).
Then just use a redirect or forward (probably a forward in your case):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/definitions", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void update(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
                            HttpServletRequest iRequest) throws Exception { 
    String decryptedId = //decrypt here
    //Do whatever else

    //either forward: or redirect:
    return "forward:my-service-2/" + decryptedId + "/definitions";
}
```